# Count occurences of a word in a tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset similar to the following sample:

```
tmj_dc_mgmt, Washington, en, 483, 457, 256, ['hiring', 'BusinessMgmt', 'Washington', 'Job']
SRiku0728, 福山市, ja, 6705, 357, 273, ['None']
BesiktaSeyma_, Akyurt, tr, 12921, 1801, 283, ['None']
AnnaKFrick, Virginia, en, 5731, 682, 1120, ['Investment', 'PPP', 'Bogota', 'jobs']
Accprimary, Manchester, en, 1650, 268, 404, ['None']
Wandii_S, Johannesburg, en, 15510, 828, 398, ['None']
```

The records inside square brackets are hashtags(excluding "None").

I am trying find the top 10 hashtags in the dataset using Spark and Scala.

I have reached this far:

```
val file = sc.textFile("/data")
val tmp1 = file
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map( p=>p(6))
  .map(_.replaceAll("\\[|\\]",""))
  .map(_.replaceAll("'",""))
  .filter(x => x != " None")
  .map(word => (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

I am not sure how to sort this and take top 10 out of this, I am new to Scala and Spark.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `top` with custom ordering to achieve what you want:

```
val r = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  "tmj_dc_mgmt, Washington, en, 483, 457, 256, ['hiring', 'BusinessMgmt', 'Washington', 'Job']",
  "SRiku0728, 福山市, ja, 6705, 357, 273, ['None']",
  "BesiktaSeyma_, Akyurt, tr, 12921, 1801, 283, ['None']",
  "AnnaKFrick, Virginia, en, 5731, 682, 1120, ['Investment', 'PPP', 'BusinessMgmt', 'Bogota', 'jobs']",
  "Accprimary, Manchester, en, 1650, 268, 404, ['None']",
  "Wandii_S, Johannesburg, en, 15510, 828, 398, ['None']",
  "Wandii_S, Johannesburg, en, 15510, 828, 398, ['Investment']"
))

val tag = ".*\\[([^\\]]*)\\]".r

val ordering = Ordering.by[(String, Int), Int](_._2)

r.collect{case tag(t) => t.split(",\\s*")}.flatMap(_.map(_.drop(1).dropRight(1))).filter(_ != "None").map(_ -> 1)
  .reduceByKey(_ + _).top(10)(ordering).foreach(println)
```

Result:

```
(BusinessMgmt,2)
(Investment,2)
(Washington,1)
(Bogota,1)
(PPP,1)
(jobs,1)
(Job,1)
(hiring,1)
```

(I modified your test data to illustrate multiple values)

Alternatively, if distinct hash tags fits in driver's memory, you can use `countByValue` instead of `reduceByKey` and perform final sorting locally:

```
r.collect{case tag(t) => t.split(",\\s*")}.flatMap(_.map(_.drop(1).dropRight(1))).filter(_ != "None")
  .countByValue().toList.sortBy(-_._2).take(10).foreach(println)
```

Also please note that I used different approach for extracting hashtags, as I believe the way you do it leads to incorrect results (when you select 6th column, you get `['hiring'`, `['Investment'`.. instead of full lists).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try using `sortBy` and `take`:

```
val sorted = tmp1.sortBy({case (word, count) => count}, ascending=false)
val top = sorted.take(10)
```

You can find more information about RDD functions on its [documentation page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

Comment: It works thanks, I also tired doing this 'val tmp1 = file.map(_.split(",")).map( p=>p(6)).map(_.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","")).map(_.replaceAll("'","")).filter(x => x != " None").map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortBy(x => (-x._2,x._1)).take(10).foreach(println)' Not sure if its correct

Comment: I think it's a valid approach as well, but it can be a little "illegible" for some.

Comment: Sorting will be a lot slower than `top` if you only want the top 10.